# WebdriverIO browser.element cannot locate existing elements in DOM

Tags: javascript, xpath, webdriver-io

Trying to automate date picker using webdriverIO. I'm able to find the DOM element in browser by using the below XPath:

`//div[starts-with(@class, "calendarBody-module__calendarTitle") and contains(., "February")]`

But, using webdriverIO's `browser.element` method, I'm getting the below error:

```
const selectedMonth = browser.element('//div[starts-with(@class, "calendarBody-module__calendarTitle") and contains(., "February")]');
```

> An element could not be located on the page using the given search
>   parameters ("./div[starts-with(@class,
>   "calendarBody-module__calendarTitle") and contains(., "February")]").

Markup of element that I'm trying to access from DOM.

```
<div data-locator-id="CalendarMonth-c6adb897-2aa5-4487-9fab-ab71fe6bf852" class="calendarBody-module__calendarTitle--3P6U5">February 2019</div>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here's what you can and can't use: https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html

Comment: Provided XPath  starts with `//div` while in stacktrace it is `./div`... Is it typo?

Comment: @Andersson nope. This is my code: `const selectedMonth = browser.element('//div[starts-with(@class, "calendarBody-module__calendarTitle") and contains(., "February")]');`

Comment: Share HTML-code sample for the same

Comment: @Andersson, I have updated the question.

Comment: XPath is correct. You might need to wait for element (if it's generated dynamically) or switch to frame in case element located in frame/iframe